Why doesn't my Dese-problem query pass the CS50 check?
"Dese" problem in problem set 1 of CS50 SQL 2023:

The Massachusetts Legislature would like to learn how much money, on average, districts spent per-pupil last year. In 3.sql, write a SQL query to find the average per-pupil expenditure. Name the column “Average District Per-Pupil Expenditure”.


Note the per_pupil_expenditure column in the expenditures table contains the average amount, per pupil, each district spent last year. You’ve been asked to find the average of this set of averages, weighting all districts equally regardless of their size.

My query:
SELECT AVG(per_pupil_expenditure) AS "Average District Per-Pupil Expenditure" FROM expenditures;

CS50 Check:

:( 3.sql produces correct result
expected "19528.99002525...", not "19528.99002525..."

What is wrong with my query?

this appears to be a rounding error.. sorry, I don't have a solution for you.   the output is ...252526 but it's expecting ...25252

Thanks for the information. I went on the CS50 Discord and for anyone running into the same problem:
SELECT CAST(AVG("per_pupil_expenditure") * 1e11 AS INTEGER) / 1e11 AS "Average District Per-Pupil Expenditure" FROM expenditures;
This query passes the CS50 check.
